# SBT xalan#serializer error in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm using Intellij to build a Play 2 web app in Scala. However, I keep getting this error inside Intellij.

```
SBT project import
     [warn]     [FAILED     ] xalan#serializer;2.7.1!serializer.jar(src):  (0ms)
     [warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
     [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/srcs/serializer-sources.jar
     [warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
     [warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/srcs/serializer-sources.jar
     [warn] ==== local: tried
     [warn]   C:\Users\ *** \.ivy2\local\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\srcs\serializer-sources.jar
     [warn] ==== public: tried
     [warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1-sources.jar
     [warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
     [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1-sources.jar
     [warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
     [warn]     ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
     [warn]     :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
     [warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
     [warn]     :: xalan#serializer;2.7.1!serializer.jar(src)
     [warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
     [warn]     [FAILED     ] xalan#serializer;2.7.1!serializer.jar(doc):  (0ms)
     [warn] ==== local: tried
     [warn]   C:\Users\ *** \.ivy2\local\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\docs\serializer-javadoc.jar
     [warn] ==== public: tried
     [warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1-javadoc.jar
     [warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
     [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1-javadoc.jar
     [warn] ==== Typesafe Releases: tried
     [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1-javadoc.jar
     [warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
     [warn]     ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
     [warn]     :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
     [warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
     [warn]     :: xalan#serializer;2.7.1!serializer.jar(doc)
     [warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

When running the project from a command line everything works correctly, it's just really annoying having this error pop up everytime I open Intellij.

Cheers

Comment: Oli did you ever find out how to fix this? I'm encountering the same error

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've just learnt to ignore it.

Comment: @OliWinks I encourage you to change the accepted answer, since I've solved the issue, it's been reproduced by others, and the accepted answer isn't actually an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After getting the same error and trying lots of stuff, I finally specified a newer version of the missing jar. I added the following to my `build.sbt`:

`libraryDependencies += "xalan" % "serializer" % "2.7.2"`

[image: It worked!]

The root problem is that the Javadoc and sources aren't available for xalan serializer v2.7.1 in the public repos that sbt checks, but they are available for the newer version. The small bump in version *shouldn't* affect anything.

An alternate solution is to not specify that sbt download Javadocs and sources.

Comment: This worked for me as well, although I had to open the project structure and remove the 2.7.1 version of the library as well.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off `[Project Settings] - [SBT] - [Download source and docs]` checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Well IntelliJ IDEA is great, but the sbt plugin has a lot of bugs... You should submit an error report [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL).

Comment: I'm getting this from doing `eclipse` in sbt with `EclipseKeys.withSource := true` in my `build.sbt`, meaning this isn't an IntelliJ thing but an sbt thing.

Comment: "When running the project from a command line everything works correctly" -> so it's IDE related. If you were using IntelliJ, you would know there are many build errors only popping up inside IntelliJ and never when using sbt directly.

Comment: Not sure why Oli didn't get the issue that he described from the command-line, but I did. I also got it in Eclipse w/ the Scala plug-in. Perhaps his configuration at CLI excluded source retrieval? 

In any case, when I looked at a number of common repos, Xalan Serializer in javadoc and source was consistently missing in 2.7.1, and consistently present in 2.7.2

Comment: Ok, if there's a solution all the better.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the project check the box for 'Use auto-import'